# Passing this to an object within an object during the constructor call

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to iron out my first compile in a long time, and I think this is the last hurdle.

I am trying to create this type of hierarchy in my design.

```
  class chin_
  {
  private:
    charon_* engine;

  public:
    chin_();
    chin_(charon_ &handle)
    {
      engine = handle;
    }
    ~chin_();
  };
```

//////////////

```
  class charon_ {
  private:
    chin_ engine_input;

  public:
    charon_(){
      engine_input = chin_(this);
    }
    ~charon_();
  };
```

I am getting errors that tell me there is no matching function for call to

```
'chio::chin_::chin()'
```

it also says, mind you this is only when I change the constructor to charon_&

```
public:
        chin_(const charon_ &handle)
        {
          engine = handle;
        }
sys/../headers/chio.h:104:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘charon::charon_* const’ to ‘const charon::charon_&’
```

When I use the * instead of & I get this instead, which is by far more baffling.

```
sys/../headers/chio.h:104:5: note: chio::chin_::chin_(const charon::charon_*)
sys/../headers/chio.h:104:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I've tried this and that, and I figure it is probably something super simple. I've tried to match my code up squarely with the examples I've found though so I don't know what else I should be trying, I'd like to be able to figure this sort of stuff out on my own. I just am not having any luck with it.

EDIT:
I update the code but I left the updated error for the bottom.

```
sys/chin.cpp:19:14: error: cannot convert ‘charon::charon_’ to ‘charon::charon_*’ in assignment
```

It takes me to this code

```
  chin_::chin_(charon_ &handle) {
    engine = handle;
  }
```

engine is defined as
charon_* engine; and handle appears to be an address and should fall right into place, but it isn't. I think I am not using this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare something like this :

```
  chin_ engine_input;
```

chin_ needs a constructor with no parameters or you have to pass the parameters to it in the initializer list, otherwise you will get the error about no matching constructor.

What you can do is either have a default constructor that takes no params. Or make engine_input a pointer and create it with :

```
 engine_input = new chin_(handle);
```

Alternatively you can pass handle to chin_ in the initializer list like this :

```
 foo::foo(charon* handle):
 chin_(handle)
{

}
```

Comment: I did that, made the empty constructor, and it got rid of a few errors but now I have one left

Comment: "sys/chin.cpp:19:14: error: cannot convert ‘charon::charon_’ to ‘charon::charon_*’ in assignment"

Comment: If you are trying to assign a variable to a pointer you have to take its address with &. Like this : 
    pointerToEngine = &engine;

Comment: I just updated the code to reflect that switch actually. I changed constructor from (const charon_* handle) to just (charon_ &handle) and that appears to get things closest to working. Now the error is for an actual line of code, finally.

Comment: Once you get all the pointer magic down, you can look into std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr.